# How do I initiate Gatsby eslinting during my deployment pipeline

Tags: deployment, gatsby, eslint, lint, eslintrc

I'm currently setting up Gatsby to replace a previous Frontend setup in a Project Template my company users. Most things are set up but I'm stuck on integrating the linting into our deployment scripts.

Our **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file calls `npm run client:lint` to run the linting for the old setup. Gatsby has its own eslint setup which works great during development, but I can't find a way to run its linting manually.

The scripts setup by Gatsby in package.json only include these:

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
```

**Is there a command I can run to kick off the linting on its own?**

Please Note: I've tried creating a custom eslint setup as per the below links, but it seemed to involve building a whole new eslint file - which I was having trouble with - So I'm hoping theres a script to run the existing linting for now that I simply haven't come across.

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/eslint/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-eslint/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
    "eslint": "eslint \"**/*.{js, jsx, json, md}\"",
  },
```

Use the `eslint` command as you wish or combined with others. This will look for all the extensions (`js`, `jsx`, `json`, `md`) in any folder of the project and will apply the detailed rules in the ESLint configuration file (`.eslintrc.json`).

It may be useful too adding a `.eslintignore` file with the following content:

```
coverage
build/Release
node_modules/
jspm_packages/
build/
.cache/
public/
```

This will avoid the parsing of that folders while running the command.

Comment: Thanks @FerranBuireu , unfortunately, even though that will use the linting module that Gatsby includes on install, it doesn't use the rules that Gatsby uses. The inclusion of .eslintrc does mean that I can call linting separately, but it also means that Gatsby's inbuilt linting is overridden (So I have to build a config file from scratch).

What I'm looking for is a way to call the inbuilt linting setup, rather than defining a new one.